# searching for the whole list of derived classes of a base class in a big C++ project

Tags: c++

I am working on a huge C++ project. I am using Netbeans to edit it, as the compilation takes place on a linux server.
I have a problem of getting the whole list of derived classes that inherit from a  base class. 
There is a protected variable in the base class and I want to takle it in the derived classes that inherit it, but how do I know who is inheriting it?

I have already launched a search on the root of the project directory for " : public BASE_CLASS " but I haven't found anything!

Is this way correct to get the derived classes?

I have searched for this issue in the forum but I haven't find anything relevant.

Any help or hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think Doxygen might be able to do this for you.

Comment: For purely ghetto, you could always rename the base temporarily and see what *breaks*, but I concur with the others. Doxygen is pretty good about generating class hierarchies if it is available to you.

Comment: @MarkRansom It does a [fairly good job](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/examples/diagrams/html/class_a.html) of it.

Comment: WhozCraig's ghetto approach will break the derived classes and everything that uses it.  Adding a pure virtual method would be a bit better since it will only break the derived classes so there will be less to filter through.

Answer (score 2):

Use [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) with [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) support to generate a hierachy graph diagram for you.

The procedure is simple:

1. Install graphviz.
2. Install doxygen.
3. Use the Doxywizard to configure the desired outputs to you.

Here is a screenshot of the doxygen diagrams tab so you have a clue on how's the interface.

[image: Doxygen diagrams tab]

And finally, here is a [link](http://www.dumux.org/doxygen-stable/html-2.2/a00040.php) with an output example to you.